# Drupal 7 Partial Search

Tags: search, drupal-7, partial

Is there a way make Drupal's search module work on partial search? For example I want to find a node which has title like "apple" when I search "app". I made a research, there are some modules. Fuzzy Search module is useful for me but it does not work.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with hook_query_alter, hook triggered before running on db , all sql statements are entering to this hook. You can modify the query as you want. But it can be a little bit difficult. Because there is 3 query you have to modify. Main search query is third one. But 2nd and 3td one are working if first query has a result. Therefore you can be confused a little bit when you are working on it. If you can't resolve the problem, write me I will send you a code block.

Comment: I found out that altering query tagged "search_node" is not enough. Can you help understand how to find the other queries that needs modification?

Comment: @D34dman you need to find out by implementing hook query alter while you are searching. So once you found out you can modify it as you wish. Hopefully, this comment helps you find the proper way.